# Integration of Bessel functions:Finding a suitable contour

Tags: improper-integrals, contour-integration, bessel-functions

I have below function to integrate;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{0}(ax)x^3}{k^2-x^2} dx$$ here $a,k$ are constants.
Since this is an odd function, I am not allowed to extend the limits from negative infinity to positive infinity. Therefore, I am planning to have a contour in the first quadrant, and apply the residue theorem. In that case, I have no idea how the Bessel functions behave in that region of the contour. Can someone please throw some light on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bessel functions on the imaginary line behave as the modified Bessel functions $(I_0(x))$ which are roughly exponentially increasing, so you'd have to take the lower quadrant to even have a chance for the far part of the contour to vanish. You will also have problems with contour integration already because of the $x=k$ point. This is why I wouldn't recommend contour integration, it does not look like the right type of integral to do that. You'll see that the integral over the far contour wouldn't vanish anyway:

The integral won't converge in the traditional sense. Asymptotically, you have
$$J_0(x)\asymp \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos (x-\pi/4) $$
so your integrand behaves as
$$\sim\int^\infty \frac{x^{2.5}\times \text{oscillatory}}{k^2-x^2}dx\sim \int^\infty \sqrt{x}\times \text{oscillatory}\,dx$$
which is asymptotically something similar to adding a sum of the form $1-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{4}+\cdots$ (*very* roughly illustrated).

I'm not sure if one could regularize this integral to assign a finite value to it, but I'd be really careful where this even comes from.

Comment: Many thanks. I got your point. I tried plotting the function in wolform alpha and see whether it converges. Well..I am not quite sure. Seems like function is symmetric about x axis. Here I took a=1.Anyways thanks alot.

Comment: Yes, it is an oscillating function with negative and positive parts. But technically, an integral/sum only converges if the contributions become smaller and smaller, eventually settling on a final value... here, if you keep going to the right, the added and subtracted areas are just getting bigger.

Comment: Thankyou very much.I understand :)

Comment: another small thing. If this function is replaced with $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{0}(ax)x}{k^2-x^2} dx$$ , then this converges. What can be the contour in that case? thanks alot

Comment: A quarter-contour wouldn't help at all, because the integral along the negative imaginary line is also nothing good. I would just take the derivative over $a$, extend the even integral over the entire real line, compute the integral, and integrate over $a$ to get the final answer. If that doesn't work, try $J_0(ax)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-iax\sin t}dt$ and see if exchange of integral order does anything useful. Maybe some series expansion or integration by parts is also useful, you never know.

Comment: thanks heaps for the suggestions