# Coutour integration involving bessel function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I throw this integration into Mathematica,

> Integrate[ (z BesselJ[0, s z])/(z^2 - w^2), {z, 0, [Infinity]}]

and get the result as,

> ConditionalExpression[BesselK[0, s/Sqrt[-(1/w^2)]], 
>    Re[s] > 0 && Im[s] == 0 && Im[w] != 0]

So it is basically telling me that, for real s, approaching the limit $w\rightarrow1+i0^+$,

$$\int_0^{+\infty}dz \frac{z J_0(s z)}{z^2-1}=K_0(-i s)$$

which I have a hard time trying to replicate by hand.

Is the above expression correct? Can you show me the magic therein?

---

relevant: [Integration of Bessel functions:Finding a suitable contour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372393/integration-of-bessel-functionsfinding-a-suitable-contour?rq=1)

Comment: i think the most straightforward way to prove this is by showing that the lhs fullfils bessel's modified differential equation

Comment: and yes it seems to be correct:
http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22

Comment: @tired Pro tip: you can link directly to a formula by hovering over the 'i' in the circle near it and getting the [permalink](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E46).

Comment: derivation of more general form of this integration can be found at: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652469.2012.758119